# Estimated Amount of Time To Create PHP RPG Game Engine

Tags: project-management, game-engine

I've been developing a text-based PHP/MySQL RPG Game Engine since early December last year, and have been wondering **how much time is spent by others, either professionals or hobbyists, on making the underlying foundation of the game (its engine)** - NOT its content, but just the engine.

With regards to the complexity of the game engine, it is about as complex as KOL's or Earth 2025 or Torn.

If anyone would like to answer, I'd appreciate it if you told me how much time was spent (in months, work-hours, any criteria you can afford to give) and how many were working on it. Any additional details would be nice, too!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been playing with a similar concept but really only in the spec stage.. have you made yours available for download yet? Any design or planning docs available?

Comment: @CaseySoftware Hahaha not yet my code is very ugly right now :( I've been working on the content of the game more than the programming... I'm quite new to game development and project management, you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hobby it took me maybe 6 months to finish a game engine, definitely a lot of it was research for best things to do.  But maybe no more than 10 - 15 hours a week (before starting I did already have experience with game development in another language) and I definitely had help every now and then from some friends.  I would guess it would take less time if you put more time into it and if you have more experience, but this is what it was for me :) Hope that helps.